# How do I get path to photo from photo library

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to get path to a photo that I pick from photo library

```
UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;
```

How do I get path from this result, cause later I need to get metadata from it.

Comment: Where do you get the UIImage ? UIImagePickerViewController  Or any other third-party plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `UIImagePickerViewController` when you pick an image you can get the URL using the `ImageUrl` Property in your `FinishedPickingMedia` event handler.

```
  private void ImagePicker_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
       var imageUrl= e.ImageUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, if you are using CrossFilePicker,

```
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                   FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                    if (fileData == null)
                        return; // user canceled file picking

                  var filepath = fileData.FilePath;

                }

                else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                {
                    var isInitialized = await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                    var isPickPhotoSupported = CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported;
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    var filePath = file.Path;
                }
```